# How to do Entity Framework/Linq join in query with where clause expressions

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, expression

I have a Entity Framework query where the where clauses' change based on several selections.
Here is my code:

```
Expression<Func<CtCsGroup, bool>> where_expression1 = x => 1 == 1;
Expression<Func<CtCsGroup, bool>> where_expression2 = x => 1 == 1;
Expression<Func<CtCsGroup, bool>> where_expression3 = x => 1 == 1;


if (selections.SearchCSGroup.NoNull() != "")
{
    where_expression1 = x => x.CsGroup.ToUpper() == selections.SearchCSGroup.ToUpper();
}

if (selections.SearchUserId.NoNull() != "")
{
    where_expression3 = x => x.UsrIdn.ToUpper() == selections.SearchUserId.ToUpper();
}

if (!selections.SearchIncludeRetires)
{
    where_expression2 = x => x.CsRetire != "Y";
}

var groupDTOs = (from g in _infobaseContext.CtCsGroup
                 .Where(where_expression1)
                 .Where(where_expression2)
                 .Where(where_expression3)
                 select new
                 {
                     UsrIdn = g.UsrIdn,
                     CsGroup = g.CsGroup,
                     CsRetire = g.CsRetire,
                     CsGroupName = "test" // n.CsGroupName
                 }).ToList();
```

I want to add a join to another table.

How do I add this to the above query?  I have tried several different formats but whenever I add it, I get an error *"(where_expression1)"* ,*"(where_expression3)"*, etc.

Thanks.

Here are some more details...

```
var groupDTOs = (from g in _infobaseContext.CtCsGroup
                         join n in _infobaseContext.TblCsGroupList
                                    on g.CsGroup equals n.CsGroup
                         select new
                         {
                             UsrIdn = g.UsrIdn,
                             CsGroup = g.CsGroup,
                             CsRetire = g.CsRetire,
                             CsGroupName =  n.CsGroupName
                         }).ToList();
```

- and this one works without the join -

```
var groupDTOs = (from g in _infobaseContext.CtCsGroup
                         .Where(where_expression1)
                         select new
                         {
                             UsrIdn = g.UsrIdn,
                             CsGroup = g.CsGroup,
                             CsRetire = g.CsRetire,
                             CsGroupName =  "test"  //n.CsGroupName
                         }).ToList();
```

- but when I add both the join and the expression -

```
var groupDTOs = (from g in _infobaseContext.CtCsGroup
                         join n in _infobaseContext.TblCsGroupList
                                    on g.CsGroup equals n.CsGroup
                         .Where(where_expression1)
                         select new
                         {
                             UsrIdn = g.UsrIdn,
                             CsGroup = g.CsGroup,
                             CsRetire = g.CsRetire,
                             CsGroupName =  n.CsGroupName
                         }).ToList();
```

- Visual Studio is giving this error:
  Argument 2: cannont convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions<System.Func<IBDataServices.Models.CtCsGroup, bool>>' to 'System.Func<char,bool>'
  [image: Error Image:]

Comment: Please use a tag indicating the exact EF version you're using. If you want to join you should use the `join` statement or, better, a navigation property. But you should show the code that throws the exception and the verbatim exception message. Your question isn't clear now.

Comment: My first reactive is why you would express conditional based `WHERE` clauses like this. Why not compose the query over multiple statements?

Comment: Everything below `Here are some more details...` is irrelevant, though I have responded to that in my answer, what you would have included was the _exact_ error message and the matching `where_expression` that created it. The error messages are quite detailed, evn though you have to learn how to interpret them.

Comment: You have `equals n.CsGroup.Where(where_expression1)`. That's impossible. You probably missed some parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we would strive to compose the query over multiple steps, rather than trying to inject multiple pre-composed predicates. You are already using *Fluent* notation to apply your predicates, so split that process out from your *Query* based expression.

You will also notice that the comparison values have been parameterised rather than letting the *linq interpreter* decide what is a query reference and what is a discrete or scalar value for us.

> You haven't posted the specific errors, however where the *linq* expression is being evaluated it the `elections.SearchCSGroup` is probably out of scope and cannot be resolved. Deliberate parameterization avoids this confusion.

```
IQueryable<CtCsGroup> groupQuery = _infobaseContext.CtCsGroup;
if (selections.SearchCSGroup.NoNull() != "")
{
    // Force the comparison against a discrete parameter value
    var selection = selections.SearchCSGroup.ToUpper();
    groupQuery = groupQuery.Where(x => x.CsGroup.ToUpper() == selection);
}

if (selections.SearchUserId.NoNull() != "")
{
    var selection = selections.SearchUserId.ToUpper();
    groupQuery = groupQuery.Where(x => x.UsrIdn.ToUpper() == selection);
}

if (!selections.SearchIncludeRetires)
{
    // NOTE: "Y" will be correctly interpreted as a discrete parameter value
    groupQuery = groupQuery.Where(x => x.CsRetire != "Y");
}

var groupDTOs = (from g in groupQuery 
                 select new
                 {
                     UsrIdn = g.UsrIdn,
                     CsGroup = g.CsGroup,
                     CsRetire = g.CsRetire,
                     CsGroupName = "test" // n.CsGroupName
                 }).ToList();
```

That last section could also be composed as a *fluent* expression, rather than a *query* based expression:

```
var groupDTOs = groupQuery.Select(g => new
                {
                    UsrIdn = g.UsrIdn,
                    CsGroup = g.CsGroup,
                    CsRetire = g.CsRetire,
                    CsGroupName = "test" // n.CsGroupName
                }).ToList();
```

This pattern helps you avoid these issues cause by trying to pass through pre-compiled predicates in the first place, especially it removes the possibility of defining the predicates with the incorrect type bindings.

This pattern is also helpful for composing expressions that have conditional sort columns or directions.

---

The final issue you have posted is a *red herring*, you have mixed up the syntax, that expression was never meant to work.

> Visual Studio is giving this error: Argument 2: cannont convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions<System.Func<IBDataServices.Models.CtCsGroup, bool>>' to 'System.Func<char,bool>'

Specifically this section:

```
join n in _infobaseContext.TblCsGroupList
          on g.CsGroup equals n.CsGroup.Where(where_expression1)
```

You probably see it now that the line break is removed, `n.CsGroup` is a string, and it itself `IEnumerable<char>` so it is assuming you want to apply the `where_expression1` predicate to the value of `n.CsGroup`

We can still join onto the composed query using the normal linq join expressions:

```
var groupDTOs = (from g in groupQuery
                 join n in _infobaseContext.TblCsGroupList
                        on g.CsGroup equals n.CsGroup 
                 select new
                 {
                     UsrIdn = g.UsrIdn,
                     CsGroup = g.CsGroup,
                     CsRetire = g.CsRetire,
                     CsGroupName = n.CsGroupName
                 }).ToList();
```

If your schema has a navigation property on `CtCsGroup` called `CsGroup` that represents the relationship between `TblCsGroupList` and `CtCsGroup` then we can use *dot notation* and the necessary *joins* will be implicit.

> **NOTE:** This makes broad assumptions about the schema and is only included to show a common structural alternative to manually defining joins

```
var groupDTOs = (from g in groupQuery
                 select new
                 {
                     UsrIdn = g.UsrIdn,
                     CsGroup = g.CsGroup,
                     CsRetire = g.CsRetire,
                     CsGroupName = g.CsGroup.CsGroupName
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I used your code above and it works great but I still need to add a simple join to it.  I want to do an outer join to TblCsGroupList on CsGroup = CsGroup to get the TblCsGroupList.CsGroupName .
I have seen different examples of how to do this but I'm not sure what is the best/simplest way to do it.
What do you recommend?

Comment: Is there a navigation property between `CsGroup` and  `TblCsGroupList`? A join is not necessary if your data structure has navigation properties defined over the Foreign Keys, So to answer what is the best way would require more information about your schema, however I've updated the post with a simple join example

Comment: That worked great.  Thanks.  FYI - I am working with legacy data that doesn't have foreign keys so using navigation properties wasn't and option.

Comment: @DanK. don't let legacy stop you ;) You can add FKs to the business models even if they are not in the database, think of a _Navigation Property_ as a predefined join. They greatly simplify the common joining logic throughout your app and guide the developers to make the right decisions